# AngularJS: Currency Formatting. Change fraction size, thousands separator and fraction separator

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, currency, currency-formatting

I wish to show prices in a specific table within my site to 3 decimal places.

Prices will be shown in Pounds, Dollars and Euros.

My currency filter seems to automatically round the price to 2 decimal places.

Also, if the currency is in Euros, Ideally, I would like to auto change the thousands separator to a `.` and decimal separator to a `,`.

Does angularjs have support for this?

**The View**

```
<div ng-controller="SpotController">
    <table class="header-table-spot-prices">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Spot Prices</th><th>Price</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="spot in spots">
                <td>{{ spot.item }}</td>

                    <!-- This needs to be 3dp -->
                <td>{{ spot.price | currency:spot.currency }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably irrelevant at this point since the original post was 2 years ago, but angular's "currency" filter takes in a symbol and a fraction size as parameters.

For example:

```
<td>{{ spot.price | currency:spot.currency : 3 }}</td>
```

Would output what you are looking for without the caveat of changing the separators based on currency. You could either create your own currency filter that first uses the angular filter, then checks the condition and alters the separators. This [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ihHsEPbjnzcUHvZizSR8?p=preview) illustrates that.

```
.filter('myCurrency', ['$filter', function($filter){
      return function(input, symbol, fractionSize){
          input = $filter('currency')(input, symbol, fractionSize);
          if(symbol === '\u20AC'){
            var tempString = "###";
            input = input.replace(",", tempString).replace(".", ",").replace(tempString, ".");
          }
          return input;
      }
    }])
```

You've probably already solved this for your needs, but putting the answer here just in case anyone else is running into a similar issue and comes across this post.

Comment: The solution presented here is insufficient in that it only replaces the first `","` with `"."`; therefore it will not work correctly for numbers above 1000000. A better solution would be: `input = input.split(",").join(tempString).replace(".", ",").split(tempString).join(".");`